# need help updating a many to many relation  in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have a 'EnterpriseEntity' and 'TagsEntity', which have a Many to Many relation in a table
called 'EnterpriseTag' this relation table just store the EnterpriseID and TagID.

My concern is about updating this with EF4. I code the following:

```cs
    //Delete old tags
    foreach(var oldTag in e.Tags.ToList())
    {
    _enterpriseRepository.dbContext.DeleteObject(oldTag);
    }

    //now insert the new ones, this may have elements from old tag list
    foreach(var newTag in newTags)
    {
    e.Tags.Add(newTag);
    }
```

As you can see the newTags list may have elements from old tag list, but i don't want to spare time checking that tag by tag.

But when i call .Savechanges() i get the following exception:

> Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is
>   not allowed.

**UPDATE:**
In my original code i had:

```cs
//This delete the Tag object, and i just want to delete the relation
    _enterpriseRepository.dbContext.DeleteObject(oldTag);
```

The correct way to do it:

```cs
//this just delete the relation, not the tag
    e.Tags.Remove(oldTag);
```

Comment: You'll need to clone the old tag. Or an alternative option is to (1) save your first round of deletes, (2) iterate through and `_enterpriseRepository.dbContext.Detach(xxxxx)` your entities in your `newTags` collection and call `xxxxx.MarkAsAdded` (if you have self-tracking entities), and (3) perform your loop that calls `e.Tags.Add(newTag);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
var oldTags = e.Tags.ToList();

foreach(var oldTag in oldTags.Except(newTags))
{
    _enterpriseRepository.dbContext.DeleteObject(oldTag);
}

foreach(var newTag in newTags.Except(oldTags))
{
    e.Tags.Add(newTag);
}
```

I'm assuming that the old tags which are in the `newTags` collection are the same object instances. If they are the same by entity key you would have to implement an `IEqualityComparer` for `Except`. Just an idea, not sure if it works.

Comment: Good this worked!. At the end I had a mayor problem (i must use e.Tags.Remove(oldTag)) that maybe solve the topic of this question, anyway i feel that using except is the right way to do it, instead of DELETE ALL and then CREATE ALL.